# I'm a bit confused why some of my values have curly brackets around them but some of them don't

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, tkinter

I am running an SQL statement to get all of the course names from the course table from a database.
I then use a for loop to place them all in a text widget with a checkbutton beside it.
Could someone please tell me why for some values it is placed with curly brackets and how to make it be placed without curly brackets?
Help appreciated!

```
query=c.execute("SELECT name FROM table").fetchall()
print(query)
for i in query:
    var=tk.Intvar()
    checkbutton = tk.Checkbutton(master,text=i)
    master.window_create("end", window=checkbutton)
    master.insert("end", "\n")
```

[image]

This is what print(query) returns
[image]

Comment: next time, please add codes instead of screenshots of codes.

Comment: Actually, you can still [edit] your question to include the code as [properly formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Please read [ask] for more information on asking good questions. You can also read this [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/16775594) asking about the reasons users shouldn't post images of code.

Comment: Don't vandalize your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write `text=i[0]` instead of just `text=i`. You are passing a tuple to `text` while it should only be a string.